# Write text with comma into a cell in CSV file using python

Tags: python, csv

I want to write text with comma into a cell in CSV file.

Input

`'1,2,3,Hello'`

Output in CSV should be

`'1,2,3','Hello'`

Answer (score 30):

Use the proper [CSV writers](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.4/library/csv.html#writer-objects):

```
>>> import csv
>>> spamWriter = csv.writer(open('eggs.csv', 'wb'))
>>> spamWriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely, Spam'])
```

Outputs:

> Spam,"Lovely, Spam"

Comment: I got the next error : AttributeError: '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'writer'.     
is there a way to do it without CSV module?

Comment: -1 Not opening csv output file in binary mode. Output on Windows: `'Spam,"Lovely, Spam"\r\r\n'`

Comment: @John - errr - yeah, per the Python documentation - http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.4/library/csv.html#csv.writer

Comment: @John - fair enough, changed.

Comment: @Dominic: Presumably you are referring to the example. You haven't noticed the somewhat vague remark earlier: """If csvfile is a file object, it must be opened with the ‘b’ flag on platforms where that makes a difference.""". Windows is the platform where it does make a difference. Sound practice is to always use binary mode on both input and output files -- this makes the script or advice-to-newbie platform-independent.

Comment: @John - am I right in thinking this doesn't apply in Python 3? (per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020053/writing-with-pythons-built-in-csv-module)

Comment: @Dominic: Python 3.1: Reading: docs say must open file with `newline=''`. Writing: docs say nothing. Actuality is that Windows needs `newline=''` otherwise you get extra `\r`.

Answer (score 9):

This is not Python specific, but is to do with the [CSV "standard"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

If you want to write a control character as part of your value, you'll need to escape the value by surrounding it in double-quotes:

```
f.write('1,2,3,45,"The Next comma I want to write and not separate to another cell, so this sentence will be whole",6,7,8')
```

Edit: Although in practice, it will be a better idea to use the CSV writer interfaces as suggested by others.  It's never a good idea to embroil yourself in the implementation details when there's a ready-rolled library that abstracts this away for you.

Comment: You'll want to add a line terminator at the end; unlike `print`, the `write` method does not supply one for you.

Answer (score 6):

> Each line of the file is a data record. Each record consists of one or more fields, separated by commas.
>
> The basic idea of separating fields with a comma is clear, but that idea gets complicated when the field data may also contain commas or even embedded line-breaks.
>
> CSV implementations may not handle such field data, or they may use quotation marks to surround the field.  -- From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

So you can use quotation marks to surround the each field text.

Suppose the input is `['1,2,3', 'Hello']`, the output to CSV should be `"1,2,3", "Hello"`, you can use codes below to achieve this.

```
>>> ",".join('"{0}"'.format(s) for s in ['1,2,3', 'Hello'])
'"1,2,3","Hello"'
```

But you will encounter problems when there are some special symbols such as `"`, `\n` and etc in text.

The python csv library has handled all the edge cases for you.

### Write to file

Can use @Dominic Rodger answer.

```
>>> import csv
>>> spamWriter = csv.writer(open('eggs.csv', 'wb'))
>>> spamWriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely, Spam'])
```

### Write to string

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/9157370/5238892.

In Python 3:

```
>>> import io
>>> import csv
>>> output = io.StringIO()
>>> csvdata = [1,2,'a','He said "what do you mean?"',"Whoa!\nNewlines!"]
>>> writer = csv.writer(output, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
>>> writer.writerow(csvdata)
59
>>> output.getvalue()
'1,2,"a","He said ""what do you mean?""","Whoa!\nNewlines!"\r\n'
```

Some details need to be changed a bit for Python 2:

```
>>> output = io.BytesIO()
>>> writer = csv.writer(output)
>>> writer.writerow(csvdata)
57L
>>> output.getvalue()
'1,2,a,"He said ""what do you mean?""","Whoa!\nNewlines!"\r\n'
```