# How do I write data into CSV format as string (not file)?

Tags: python, string, csv

I want to cast data like `[1,2,'a','He said "what do you mean?"']` to a CSV-formatted string.

Normally one would use `csv.writer()` for this, because it handles all the crazy edge cases (comma escaping, quote mark escaping, CSV dialects, etc.) The catch is that `csv.writer()` expects to output to a file object, not to a string.

My current solution is this somewhat hacky function:

```
def CSV_String_Writeline(data):
    class Dummy_Writer:
        def write(self,instring):
            self.outstring = instring.strip("\r\n")
    dw = Dummy_Writer()
    csv_w = csv.writer( dw )
    csv_w.writerow(data)
    return dw.outstring
```

Can anyone give a more elegant solution that still handles the edge cases well?

Edit: Here's how I ended up doing it:

```
def csv2string(data):
    si = StringIO.StringIO()
    cw = csv.writer(si)
    cw.writerow(data)
    return si.getvalue().strip('\r\n')
```

Comment: In Python 3, `StringIO()` is in the `io` library.

Comment: Since "\r" and "\n" are considered whitespace, you can actually just use "strip" with no argument: `return si.getvalue().strip()`--unless for some reason you need to preserve spaces at the end.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You could use [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) instead of your own `Dummy_Writer`:

> This module implements a file-like class, `StringIO`, that reads and writes a string buffer (also known as memory files).

There is also [`cStringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-cStringIO), which is a faster version of the `StringIO` class.

Comment: cStringIO was gone away since python 3.0. Please use `io.StringIO` instead

Answer (score 258):

In Python 3:

```
>>> import io
>>> import csv
>>> output = io.StringIO()
>>> csvdata = [1,2,'a','He said "what do you mean?"',"Whoa!\nNewlines!"]
>>> writer = csv.writer(output, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
>>> writer.writerow(csvdata)
59
>>> output.getvalue()
'1,2,"a","He said ""what do you mean?""","Whoa!\nNewlines!"\r\n'
```

Some details need to be changed a bit for Python 2:

```
>>> output = io.BytesIO()
>>> writer = csv.writer(output)
>>> writer.writerow(csvdata)
57L
>>> output.getvalue()
'1,2,a,"He said ""what do you mean?""","Whoa!\nNewlines!"\r\n'
```

Comment: Good example. :)

As a sidenote, what is the usual behaviour when encountering newlines inside a CSV file? Is `\n` ok to have in the middle of data, but `\r\n` indicates the end of a record no matter where it appears? (Assuming you're on a platform that uses `\r\n` as the line terminator.)

Comment: I'm not sure. I would have expected `\r\n` myself because the default parameter for `io.StringIO()` is `newline=None` which enables universal newlines mode, which should automatically use the correct newline style according to your platform. I'm kind of puzzled by this behaviour myself.

Comment: @Li-aungYip: I've opened a [question about this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157623/unexpected-behavior-of-universal-newline-mode-with-stringio-and-csv-modules).

Comment: Maintaining the `\n` as part of the field data seems like a sane thing to do (because it could legitimately appear as part of text data.)

Comment: Should be `output = StringIO.StringIO()`, `io.StringIO()` will raise TypeError: string argument expected, got 'str'.

Comment: @Marboni: StringIO is gone in Python 3 (which is what my solution is written in), and I can't reproduce that error in Python 2.7.3 - although I do get a TypeError in the `writer.writerow(...)` line (`unicode argument expected, got 'str'`). Will look into this.

Comment: @Marboni: Thanks for the heads-up: I [found the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120127/how-can-i-use-io-stringio-with-the-csv-module) with the help of StackOverflow. In Python 2, you need `io.BytesIO()` instead of `io.StringIO()`.

Comment: @Marboni: In Python 2.7.9 it works with StringIO.StringIO() or io.BytesIO().

Comment: Curious: why do you have the `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` parameter?

Comment: doesn't work on python3.6: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Comment: @nz_21: I just re-tested it - works perfectly fine. The second example (written for Python 2, as explicitly stated) will throw that error, of course.

Answer (score 9):

since i use this quite a lot to stream results asynchronously from **sanic** back to the user as csv data i wrote the following snippet for **Python 3**.

The snippet lets you reuse the same StringIo buffer over and over again.

```py
import csv
from io import StringIO


class ArgsToCsv:
    def __init__(self, seperator=","):
        self.seperator = seperator
        self.buffer = StringIO()
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.buffer)

    def stringify(self, *args):
        self.writer.writerow(args)
        value = self.buffer.getvalue().strip("\r\n")
        self.buffer.seek(0)
        self.buffer.truncate(0)
        return value + "\n"
```

example:

```py
csv_formatter = ArgsToCsv()

output += csv_formatter.stringify(
    10,
    """
    lol i have some pretty
    "freaky"
    strings right here \' yo!
    """,
    [10, 20, 30],
)
```

Check out further usage at the github gist: [source and test](https://gist.github.com/sloev/1625dd0020bb84140afcb2d2cb741ef1)

Answer (score 7):

I found the answers, all in all, a bit confusing. For Python 2, this usage worked for me:

```
import csv, io

def csv2string(data):
    si = io.BytesIO()
    cw = csv.writer(si)
    cw.writerow(data)
    return si.getvalue().strip('\r\n')

data=[1,2,'a','He said "what do you mean?"']
print csv2string(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the version that works for utf-8. csvline2string for just one line, without linebreaks at the end, csv2string for many lines, with linebreaks:

```
import csv, io

def csvline2string(one_line_of_data):
    si = BytesIO.StringIO()
    cw = csv.writer(si)
    cw.writerow(one_line_of_data)
    return si.getvalue().strip('\r\n')

def csv2string(data):
    si = BytesIO.StringIO()
    cw = csv.writer(si)
    for one_line_of_data in data:
        cw.writerow(one_line_of_data)
    return si.getvalue()
```

Answer (score 0):

i adopt the answer of @user2099484 above, with a small amendment for unicode

```
import csv, io

def csv2string(data):
    si = io.BytesIO()
    cw = csv.writer(si)
    data = [f.encode('utf-8') if type(f) == unicode else f for f in data]
    cw.writerow(data)
    return si.getvalue().strip('\r\n')

data=[1,2,'a','He said "what do you mean?"']
print csv2string(data)
data2=[1,2,u'שלום','He said "what do you mean?"']
print csv2string(data2)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import csv
from StringIO import StringIO
with open('file.csv') as file:
    file = file.read()

stream = StringIO(file)

csv_file = csv.DictReader(stream)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged, you should add some clarification to your answer