# Unexpected behavior of universal newline mode with StringIO and csv modules

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, newline

Consider the following (Python 3.2 under Windows):

```
>>> import io
>>> import csv
>>> output = io.StringIO()         # default parameter newline=None
>>> csvdata = [1, 'a', 'Whoa!\nNewlines!']
>>> writer = csv.writer(output, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
>>> writer.writerow(csvdata)
25
>>> output.getvalue()
'1,"a","Whoa!\nNewlines!"\r\n'
```

Why is there a single `\n` - shouldn't it have been [converted to `\r\n`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) since universal newlines mode is enabled?

> With this enabled, on *input*, the lines endings `\n`, `\r`, or `\r\n`
>   are translated to `\n` before being returned to the caller.
>   Conversely, on *output*, `\n` is translated to the system default line
>   separator, `os.linesep`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "single" `\n` occurs as a data character inside the third field. Consequently that field is quoted so that a csv reader will treat it as part of the data. It is NOT a "line terminator" (should be called a row separator) or part thereof. To get a better appreciation of the quoting, remove the `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`.

The `\r\n` is produced because csv terminates rows with the `dialect.lineterminator` whose default is `\r\n`. In other words, the "universal newlines" setting is ignored.

**Update**

The 2.7 and 3.2 docs for `io.StringIO` are virtually identical as far as the *newline* arg is concerned.

> The newline argument works like that of TextIOWrapper. The default is
>   to do no newline translation.

We'll examine the first sentence below. The second sentence is true for output, depending on your interpretation of "default" and "newline translation".

TextIOWrapper docs:

> newline can be None, '', '\n', '\r', or '\r\n'. It controls the
>   handling of line endings. If it is None, universal newlines is
>   enabled. With this enabled, on input, the lines endings '\n', '\r', or
>   '\r\n' are translated to '\n' before being returned to the caller.
>   Conversely, on output, '\n' is translated to the system default line
>   separator, os.linesep. If newline is any other of its legal values,
>   that newline becomes the newline when the file is read and it is
>   returned untranslated. On output, '\n' is converted to the newline.

Python 3.2 on Windows:

```
>>> from io import StringIO as S
>>> import os
>>> print(repr(os.linesep))
'\r\n'
>>> ss = [S()] + [S(newline=nl) for nl in (None, '', '\n', '\r', '\r\n')]
>>> for x, s in enumerate(ss):
...     m = s.write('foo\nbar\rzot\r\n')
...     v = s.getvalue()
...     print(x, m, len(v), repr(v))
...
0 13 13 'foo\nbar\rzot\r\n'
1 13 12 'foo\nbar\nzot\n'
2 13 13 'foo\nbar\rzot\r\n'
3 13 13 'foo\nbar\rzot\r\n'
4 13 13 'foo\rbar\rzot\r\r'
5 13 15 'foo\r\nbar\rzot\r\r\n'
>>>
```

Line 0 shows that the "default" that you get with no `newline` arg involves no translation of `\n` (or any other character). **It is certainly NOT converting `'\n'` to `os.linesep`**

Line 1 shows that what you get with `newline=None` (should be the same as line 0, shouldn't it??) is in effect *INPUT* universal newlines translation -- bizarre!

Line 2: `newline=''` does no change, like line 0. It is certainly NOT converting `'\n'` to `''`.

Lines 3, 4, and 5: as the docs say, `'\n'` is converted to the value of the `newline` arg.

The equivalent Python 2.X code produces equivalent results with Python 2.7.2.

**Update 2** For consistency with built-in `open()`, the default should be `os.linesep`, as documented. To get the no-translation-on-output behaviour, use `newline=''`. Note: the `open()` docs are much clearer. I'll submit a bug report tomorrow.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed explanation (and exploration). I think I'm looking into an abyss here.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Wait till you look at *input*.

Answer (score 4):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/io#io.StringIO) for StringIO:

> The newline argument works like that of TextIOWrapper. The default is to do no newline translation.

So StringIO is not doing any newline translation normally. That default makes sense - StringIO isn't writing to disk, so it doesn't need to translate to the platform-specific newlines.

As John pointed out, the csv module does its own universal newlines, but only for row endings, not for newlines within strings.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Apart from `u'foo'` instead of `'foo'`, the 2.7 docs for `io.StringIO` and `io.TextIOWrapper` are identical as far as the `newline` arg is concerned. You maust have read the TIOW docs which lie about `os.linesep`. See my updated answer.

Comment: @JohnMachin: You're right. But then the Python docs are inconsistent: See the part I linked to and quoted in my question. The docs for `TextIOWrapper` say that the default (`newline=None`) behavior is to *do* the translation. The docs for `StringIO` say the default behavior is *not* to do the translation. Puzzled.