# How can I use io.StringIO() with the csv module?

Tags: python, csv, unicode, python-2.7

I tried to backport a Python 3 program to 2.7, and I'm stuck with a strange problem:

```
>>> import io
>>> import csv
>>> output = io.StringIO()
>>> output.write("Hello!")            # Fail: io.StringIO expects Unicode
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unicode argument expected, got 'str'
>>> output.write(u"Hello!")           # This works as expected.
6L
>>> writer = csv.writer(output)       # Now let's try this with the csv module:
>>> csvdata = [u"Hello", u"Goodbye"]  # Look ma, all Unicode! (?)
>>> writer.writerow(csvdata)          # Sadly, no.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unicode argument expected, got 'str'
```

According to the docs, [`io.StringIO()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/io.html#io.StringIO) returns an in-memory stream for Unicode text. It works correctly when I try and feed it a Unicode string manually. Why does it fail in conjunction with the `csv` module, even if all the strings being written are Unicode strings? Where does the `str` come from that causes the Exception?

<sub>(I do know that I can use `StringIO.StringIO()` instead, but I'm wondering what's wrong with `io.StringIO()` in this scenario)</sub>

Comment: I suspect the `from __future__ import unicode_literals` might cause this in python2 when subclassing from stdlib modules that use 'bytestring literals'

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The Python 2.7 `csv` module doesn't support Unicode input: see the [note at the beginning of the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html#module-csv).

It seems that you'll have to encode the Unicode strings to byte strings, and use `io.BytesIO`, instead of `io.StringIO`.

The [examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples) section of the documentation includes examples for a `UnicodeReader` and `UnicodeWriter` wrapper classes (thanks @AlexeyKachayev for the pointer).

Comment: I had exactly the same problem as the OP (although only in my unit tests, not on the prompt, weirdly). Anyway, using `io.StringIO` in Python 3 and `io.BytesIO` in Python 2, as suggested in this answer, solved my problem.

Answer (score 24):

Please use StringIO.StringIO().

http://docs.python.org/library/io.html#io.StringIO

http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html

`io.StringIO` is a class. It handles Unicode. It reflects the preferred Python 3 library structure.

`StringIO.StringIO` is a class. It handles strings. It reflects the legacy Python 2 library structure.

Comment: AttributeError: type object '_io.StringIO' has no attribute 'StringIO'

Answer (score 15):

I found this when I tried to serve a CSV file via Flask directly without creating the CSV file on the file system. This works:

```
import io
import csv

data = [[u'cell one', u'cell two'], [u'cell three', u'cell four']]

output = io.BytesIO()
writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter=',')
writer.writerows(data)
your_csv_string = output.getvalue()
```

### See also

- [More about CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41585079/562769)
- [The Flask part](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30043470/562769)
- [A few notes about Strings / Unicode](https://martin-thoma.com/strings/)

Answer (score 4):

From `csv` documentation:

> The csv module doesn’t directly support reading and writing Unicode,
>   but it is 8-bit-clean save for some problems with ASCII NUL
>   characters. So you can write functions or classes that handle the
>   encoding and decoding for you as long as you avoid encodings like
>   UTF-16 that use NULs. UTF-8 is recommended.

You can find example of `UnicodeReader`, `UnicodeWriter` here http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 1):

To use CSV reader/writer with 'memory files' in python 2.7:

```
from io import BytesIO
import csv

csv_data = """a,b,c
foo,bar,foo"""

# creates and stores your csv data into a file the csv reader can read (bytes)
memory_file_in = BytesIO(csv_data.encode(encoding='utf-8'))

# classic reader
reader = csv.DictReader(memory_file_in)

# writes a csv file
fieldnames = reader.fieldnames  # here we use the data from the above csv file
memory_file_out = BytesIO()     # create a memory file (bytes)

# classic writer (here we copy the first file in the second file)
writer = csv.DictWriter(memory_file_out, fieldnames)
for row in reader:
    print(row)
    writer.writerow(row)
```