# Writing a CSV from Flask framework

Tags: python, csv, flask

I have no problems writing a CSV outside of the Flask framework. But when I try to write it from Flask, it writes to the CSV, but only on one line.

Here is the template I'm following

```
@app.route('/download')
def download():
    csv = """"REVIEW_DATE","AUTHOR","ISBN","DISCOUNTED_PRICE"
"1985/01/21","Douglas Adams",0345391802,5.95
"1990/01/12","Douglas Hofstadter",0465026567,9.95
"1998/07/15","Timothy ""The Parser"" Campbell",0968411304,18.99
"1999/12/03","Richard Friedman",0060630353,5.95
"2004/10/04","Randel Helms",0879755725,4.50"""
    response = make_response(csv)
    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=books.csv"
    return response
```

This writes the CSV perfectly, but when I try with my code, I get one long row.

My code:

```
@app.route('/download')
def post(self):

    # lots of code

    csvList.append([all,my,data,goes,here])

    csvList = str(re.sub('\[|\]','',str(csvList)))  # convert to a string; remove brackets

    response = make_response(csvList)
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=myCSV.csv"
    return response
```

My output:

```
Nashville Physician Service Ce,Treasury Specialist,Brentwood,TN,(615) 507-1646,La Petite Academy,Afternoon Teacher Aide,Goodlettsville,TN,(615) 859-2034,Nashville Physician Service Ce,Denial Resolution Specialist,Brentwood,TN,(615) 507-1646
```

Thanks.

**EDIT:** I tried just about all the answers and they worked for the most part, but I chose vectorfrog's because it fit with what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: You should probably be using the csv (https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module.

Comment: Also, this is a more idiomatic way to create a file for download in flask: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/32/

Comment: Thanks, @DavidK.Hess! I've been not only trying to learn python basics, but really trying to write idiomatic code. This definitely helps.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45608450/562769

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I did something like this recently, I found that I needed to first place the csv into a StringIO and then return the StringIO.  If you want the csv to be a download, here's what I did:

```
import StringIO
import csv
from flask import make_response

@app.route('/download')
def post(self):
    si = StringIO.StringIO()
    cw = csv.writer(si)
    cw.writerows(csvList)
    output = make_response(si.getvalue())
    output.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=export.csv"
    output.headers["Content-type"] = "text/csv"
    return output
```

Comment: In python3 `StringIO` lives in the `io` module instead of the `StringIO` module: `import io; io.StringIO()`

Comment: Nice! Really worked for me.

Comment: @Charlotte super appreciate the update!

Comment: @vectorfrog Does doing this auto-download the file to the client machine?

Comment: @UjjwalMohanty, yep, this will download the csv file in the client's browser.

Comment: @vectorfrog Thanks for the reply and the original answer. It worked. I have another question regarding this though. Can this be done using Javascript. I need to save the data present in the html to the csv file. And I am using ajax calls in Javascript to read the html data in my python definition in app.py. I have created a button which calls the function in my JS file and transfers the data to python definition. But in this method the csv is not downloaded. Any idea what might be the issue?

Comment: @UjjwalMohanty, I've never done it before, but if you want to create the csv using browser rendered JS, you could try method at https://javascript.plainenglish.io/javascript-create-file-c36f8bccb3be

Answer (score 9):

One alternative::

```
from flask import Flask, make_response
import pyexcel as pe
import StringIO # py2.7, for python3, please use import io

app = Flask(__name__)

data = [
    ["REVIEW_DATE","AUTHOR","ISBN","DISCOUNTED_PRICE"],
    ["1985/01/21","Douglas Adams",'0345391802',5.95],
    ["1990/01/12","Douglas Hofstadter",'0465026567',9.95],
    ["1998/07/15","Timothy \"The Parser\" Campbell",'0968411304',18.99],
    ["1999/12/03","Richard Friedman",'0060630353',5.95],
    ["2004/10/04","Randel Helms",'0879755725',4.50]
]

@app.route('/download')
def download():
    sheet = pe.Sheet(data)
    io = StringIO.StringIO()
    sheet.save_to_memory("csv", io)
    output = make_response(io.getvalue())
    output.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=export.csv"
    output.headers["Content-type"] = "text/csv"
    return output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug=True
    app.run()
```

Another alternative is to use Flask-Excel:

```
from flask import Flask, make_response
from flask.ext import excel

app = Flask(__name__)

data = [
    ["REVIEW_DATE","AUTHOR","ISBN","DISCOUNTED_PRICE"],
    ["1985/01/21","Douglas Adams",'0345391802',5.95],
    ["1990/01/12","Douglas Hofstadter",'0465026567',9.95],
    ["1998/07/15","Timothy \"The Parser\" Campbell",'0968411304',18.99],
    ["1999/12/03","Richard Friedman",'0060630353',5.95],
    ["2004/10/04","Randel Helms",'0879755725',4.50]
]

@app.route('/download')
def download():
    output = excel.make_response_from_array(data, 'csv')
    output.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=export.csv"
    output.headers["Content-type"] = "text/csv"
    return output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug=True
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to add newlines. Anyway, your method of making `csv`s (printing the list and removing brackets from it) is not the best way to do it. Try this instead:

```
csvList = '\n'.join(','.join(row) for row in csvList)
```

Or use the `csv` module:

```
import io, csv

dest = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(dest)

for row in csvList:
    writer.writerow(row)

# Now dest is a file-like object containing your csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `csv` is just a plain text format you shoud make shure that new line separator - `\n` is present at the end of every line you have

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure I understand your objective, but you can try the [str.join()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method. So, if you wanted to make a quick CSV output from a list of lists:

```
csvList= [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['asdf', '7', 'eight']]
csvStrings= []
for csvLine in csvList:
    csvStrings += [",".join(csvLine)]
print "\n".join(csvStrings)
```