# Flask: Download a csv file on clicking a button

Tags: javascript, python, json, csv, flask

I just got started with Flask/Python. What I want to achieve is that I have a download button in my HTML and it calls the following function:

```
function downloadPlotCSV() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/getPlotCSV",
            type: "post",
            success: function(data) {
                dataPlot = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(dataPlot);
            }
        });
    }
```

The incomplete flask code is:

```
@app.route('/getPlotCSV', methods = ['POST'])
def plotCSV():
    data = open("outputs/Adjacency.csv")
```

The problem I am facing is that I cannot find a way to download this csv file or return it as a JSON string so I can download it using Javascript. Any idea how I can send it as JSON or maybe download it via Flask itself? What's the best way?

Comment: As a side note, irrelevant but useful to the post, if what you really want is to get a csv which is really a json to parse it into a javascript object, `mimetype='text/json'` allows to skip the parsing part.

Comment: And I would change the `type` argument of the `downloadPlotCSV` method to `GET` (idem in the Python code part).

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Here is one way to download a CSV file with no Javascript:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from flask import Flask, Response
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return '''
        <html><body>
        Hello. <a href="/getPlotCSV">Click me.</a>
        </body></html>
        '''

@app.route("/getPlotCSV")
def getPlotCSV():
    # with open("outputs/Adjacency.csv") as fp:
    #     csv = fp.read()
    csv = '1,2,3\n4,5,6\n'
    return Response(
        csv,
        mimetype="text/csv",
        headers={"Content-disposition":
                 "attachment; filename=myplot.csv"})


app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Hi Bob I met a problem when I implemented your solution. the rows are concatenation of strings, like row_1 = string_1 + ',' + string_2 + ',' + ..... If strings have comma inside, the characters behind the comma will be moved to next column. How can I solve it? Thx.

Comment: Excelent and simple solution, I'm search a little time for a solution like this.
congrats!

Comment: Hi Rob, if I want to redirect to success page or error page after downloading of file. how this can be done? Can you pls explain.

Answer (score 58):

You can use [`flask.send_file()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/?highlight=send_file#flask.send_file) to send a static file:

```
from flask import send_file

@app.route('/getPlotCSV') # this is a job for GET, not POST
def plot_csv():
    return send_file(
        'outputs/Adjacency.csv',
        mimetype='text/csv',
        download_name='Adjacency.csv',
        as_attachment=True
    )
```

<sub>Prior to Flask 2.0, `download_name` was called `attachment_filename`.</sub>

Comment: This works. As a side note, if the user want to get a csv which is really a json to parse it into a javascript object, `mimetype='text/json'` allows to skip the parsing part.

Comment: Considered unsafe nowadays, I guess. @Anyone: Please refer to this function instead incl. an example: [send_from_directory](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory).

Answer (score -3):

Firstly you need to import from flask `make_response`, that will generate your response and create variable, something like `response`.
Secondly, make `response.content_type = "text/csv"`
Thirdly - return your response.

Comment: I used a different approach as answered. Anyways, will try out your method too. Thanks :)

Comment: I see. In your case you return *JSONified data from* the file, while I return *file*.