# How to pass pandas dataframe to button in web for download file(.csv or .xlsx) with flask, Python 2.7

Tags: python, pandas, csv, flask, xlsx

My web application has visualization function for user see chart(Average, Standard Deviation) by `from ...day` `to ...day`(Start Date to End Date), where(Production line) then request to SQL for connect database. **This is visualization form.** :

[image]

After request of user my web app will show about 31 charts and I add 3 buttons for download file every chart in web look like this. (**example. number 1,2 of chart**) :

[image]
[image]

And this is **my javascript for create chart and , etc** in file `.html` (spc_chart.html) **but** don't yet pass dataframe to `.html`:

[image]

I have all pandas dataframe of Avg Chart Data, Std Chart Data, Raw Data(use calculate for Avg,Std) in 3 arrays(name is: ChartDataAvg, ChartDataStd, RawData).

I just know that how to download file must will add `href="/..."` at each of button and set `@app.route('/...')` in python then send SQL to each def of `@app.route('/...')` and pass dataframe to web after calculated. ref([Flask: Download a csv file on clicking a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30024948/flask-download-a-csv-file-on-clicking-a-button)) **But** I don't know how to pass SQL request of user from def in another `@app.route(/...)`.

**Is there any way to pass all pandas dataframe to button for download file in each of the chart 1, 2, 3,... or send SQL to def in another `app.route`???**

Answer (score 3):

You can first make your dataframe in a csv format with the following function:

```
def build_csv_data(dataframe):
    csv_data = dataframe.to_csv(index=False, encoding='utf-8')
    csv_data = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + quote(csv_data)
    return csv_data
```

Then create a callback function for your download link as follows:

```
@app.callback(Output('download_link', 'href'), [<your dataframe input variables>])
    def callback_build_csv_data(dataframe):           
        return build_csv_data(dataframe)
```

Finally in your page layout add the download link as follows:

```
html.A('Download Data',
        id='download_link',
        download="rawdata.csv",
        href="",
        target="_blank"
        ),
```

Hope this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved for this:

```
@app.route('/download-data/')
def download_data():
    """Download the data to the user as a csv..."""

    # Retrieve the data from  user's request
    data = cache.get("my_data")

    if not data:
        return jsonify({
            "ERROR": "data not found."
        })

    # -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
    
    # Load from the format it was saved in
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)

    csv_data = df.to_csv(index=False, encoding='utf-8')

    response = Response(csv_data,mimetype='text/csv')
    response.headers.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment", filename="data.csv")

    return response
```