# Unable to write byte-like string using csv.writer in Python3

Tags: string, python-3.x, csv

I declare a `BytesIO()` object to write through `csv.writer` as:

```
lines = ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
writer_file =  io.BytesIO()
writer = csv.writer(writer_file)        
writer.writerow(str(lines).encode("utf-8"))
```

but I get an error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

but when I check the types, I get a `bytes` object.

```
In [14]: type(str(lines).encode("utf-8"))
Out[14]: bytes
```

What does this mean?

Note: I can't use `io.StringIO()` to keep this code compatible for python2.
(Basing my assumptions on this: [different io types for csv in python 2 and 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9157370/3285138) )

Comment: You can use `io.StringIO` and still be compatible with python2... You would be using unicode strings on python3, but no reason why this would make a difference in the outcome.. Both python versions would be using their `str` class. Another option is to just use always Unicode... It is better anyway

Comment: @JBernardo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120127/how-can-i-use-io-stringio-with-the-csv-module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the time being, I just check the python system version and apply the appropriate `io.*IO()` object for csv writing as:

```
import sys

lines = ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
if sys.version_info >= (3.0):
    writer_file =  io.StringIO()
else:
    writer_file =  io.BytesIO()

writer = csv.writer(writer_file)        
writer.writerow(lines)
```