# translate SQL query to flask-sqlalchemy statements

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am changing my old SQL implementations of a web app to flask-alchemy and having some difficulties about the correspondence.

The old code looks like this. It does the name query about some properties and returns a csv style text.

```
header = 'id,display_name,city,state,latitude,longitude\n'
base_query = '''SELECT id, bbs_id, city, state, 
                     latitude, longitude FROM mytable'''
conn = sqlite3.connect(path.join(ROOT,'db.sqlite')) 
c = conn.execute(base_query+'WHERE name=?', (name,))
results = c.fetchall()
conn.close()
rows = [','.join(map(str, row)) for row in results]
return header + rows
```

The new code

```
header = 'id,display_name,city,state,latitude,longitude\n'
cols = ['id', 'bbs_id', 'city', 'state', 'latitude', 'longitude'] 
users = User.query.filter_by(name=name).all()
rows = ''
for user in users:
    rows += ','.join([user.id, user.bbs_id, user.city, user.state, user.latitude, user.longitude]) + '\n'
return header + rows
```

I am not happy with the new code since it's so verbose.

- Is there a way to select only the ones in `cols` instead of query all columns and then pick the needed columns?
- If not, is it possible to write the `','.join()` more succinctly? It seems `user['id']` does not work and I have to do `user.id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems that you want to output comma separated values, use the [proper module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) for that. You can override the query's entities with [with_entities](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.with_entities):

```
import csv
import io

...

output = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(output)

headers = ['id', 'bbs_id', 'city', 'state', 'latitude', 'longitude'] 
writer.writerow(headers)

# The other option is to db.session.query(...)
users = User.query.with_entities(
    *(getattr(User, hdr) for hdr in headers)
).filter_by(name=name)
writer.writerows(users)

return output.getvalue()
```

If you're still on python 2, [replace `io.StringIO` with `io.BytesIO`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120127/how-can-i-use-io-stringio-with-the-csv-module).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a result set as before, you can do:

```
results = db.session.query(*(getattr(User, col) for col in cols)).filter_by(...)
```

and then you can use `results` as you did before.

If, OTOH, you want to use the ORM, you can use [`load_only`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_columns.html#sqlalchemy.orm.load_only):

```
users = User.query.options(*(load_only(col) for col in cols)).filter_by(...)
rows = "".join(",".join(*(getattr(u, col) for col in cols)) + "\n" for u in users)
```

Comment: what about the `filter_by(name=name)`?

Comment: @nos Added that to the examples.