# Regex to convert csv to pipe-separated

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have the following string:

```
s = "XIDJIJFHD8","Gothika","a0KU000000JMYCrMAP","USA","English","Sub & Audio","VOD","SD","01/01/2011 00:00:00.000000","12/31/2049 00:00:00.000000",,"Confirmed",,,,"Feature",,"2003-11-21","2004-03-23",,"R","for violence, brief language and nudity.","2024863","6000008953",,,"10.5240/A6FC-02AE-8093-3B05-6240-T","10.5240/D052-B470-0D01-25DF-DA91-4","2024863_6000008953","idwb:2024863_6000008953","CA-0000950613"
```

I need to convert it to 'pipe-separated'. Fields are enclosed with quotations `"`, though if a field is empty, it won't have anything. The number of `|` in the final output should be 31. Here is what I have so far:

```
re.sub(r'(\,|\")(,)(,|\")', '|', s)
```

However, the length of the above has only 23. What would the correct regex be?

Or, even better, maybe I could just do it directly in the csv module. Something like:

```
string_with_pipes = csv.write(s, delimiter="|")
```

Note that I just want to get a modified string, not actually save a file.

Comment: The regex doesn't work because successive commas are replaced by one pipe. They should in fact be replaced with a pipe for each one

Comment: @ruaridhw right, so how would that be done?

Comment: See my answer below :) Just a small tweak to the regular expression you had originally pretty much by adding `(?` to the start of the first and third groups. You also don't need to escape , or " characters and the | can be replaced with a selection of allowable characters. `(\,|\")` becomes `(?[,"])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [no need for regular expressions](https://xkcd.com/208/). You can do it with a combination of `csv.reader()` and `csv.writer()` using a temporary buffer for which we'll use `StringIO`:

```
import csv
from StringIO import StringIO


s = '"XIDJIJFHD8","Gothika","a0KU000000JMYCrMAP","USA","English","Sub & Audio","VOD","SD","01/01/2011 00:00:00.000000","12/31/2049 00:00:00.000000",,"Confirmed",,,,"Feature",,"2003-11-21","2004-03-23",,"R","for violence, brief language and nudity.","2024863","6000008953",,,"10.5240/A6FC-02AE-8093-3B05-6240-T","10.5240/D052-B470-0D01-25DF-DA91-4","2024863_6000008953","idwb:2024863_6000008953","CA-0000950613"'

reader = csv.reader([s])

buffer = StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(buffer, delimiter="|")
writer.writerows(reader)

buffer.seek(0)
print(buffer.getvalue())
```

Prints:

```
XIDJIJFHD8|Gothika|a0KU000000JMYCrMAP|USA|English|Sub & Audio|VOD|SD|01/01/2011 00:00:00.000000|12/31/2049 00:00:00.000000||Confirmed||||Feature||2003-11-21|2004-03-23||R|for violence, brief language and nudity.|2024863|6000008953|||10.5240/A6FC-02AE-8093-3B05-6240-T|10.5240/D052-B470-0D01-25DF-DA91-4|2024863_6000008953|idwb:2024863_6000008953|CA-0000950613
```

Comment: great, I like this approach the best. However when I do `writerows` I get an error: TypeError: unicode argument expected, got 'str'. Any idea?

Comment: Doesn't look like this can be done directly in python2.7 -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13120279/651174. Would you be able to modify your answer to write to bytes?

Comment: @David542 yeah, was looking for a single Python 2 and 3 compatible way. Updated with a separate "BytesIO" based Python 2.x solution. Thanks.

Comment: cool -- it actually works also if you just change the import statement `from StringIO import StringIO`

Comment: I updated your import statement in the first one and now it works for both python 2 and 3, so no need for the second answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The successive commas are being included in a single match.

You want a regex which doesn't include them in the replacement itself but ensures that they're there

```
re.sub(r'(?<=[,"])(,)(?=[,"])', '|', s)
```

This uses lookahead and lookbehinds to check that the , or " is present without replacing them.

1. `(,)` Match a comma
2. `(?<=[,"])` Immediately preceded by either a comma or double quote
3. `(?=[,"])` Immediately followed by either a comma or double quote

The `(?` in the first and third groups ensure that these groups are not included in the replacement