# Write a header at every logfile that is created with a time-rotating logger

Tags: python, logging

I've made a time-rotating logger which creates a new logfile at midnight. In my logfile I want to write a header at the top of every file. I'm looking for an efficient way to call a function which writes this header to the logfile upon the moment that the file is created.

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

# create time-rotating log handler
logHandler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(logfile, when='midnight')

# create logger
self.log = logging.getLogger('MyTimeRotatingLogger')
self.log.addHandler(logHandler)
```

Comment: Does it work when you override `doRollover`?

Comment: Yes that was all that needed to be done! I've posted the answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've solved it! Basically all that needs to be done is overriding the `doRollover` method of the `TimedRotatingFileHandler`, also some code is needed in this new parent class in order to pass the logging instance and set the header content. Hereby an extensive example for people who encounter a similar situation.

```
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

class MyTimedRotatingFileHandler(TimedRotatingFileHandler):
    def __init__(self, logfile, when, interval):
        super(MyTimedRotatingFileHandler, self).__init__(logfile, when, interval)
        self._header = ""
        self._log = None

    def doRollover(self):
        super(MyTimedRotatingFileHandler, self).doRollover()
        if self._log is not None and self._header != "":
            self._log.info(self._header)

    def setHeader(self, header):
        self._header = header

    def configureHeaderWriter(self, header, log):
        self._header = header
        self._log = log

# create time-rotating log handler
logHandler = MyTimedRotatingFileHandler(logfile, when='midnight')
form = '%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s'
logFormatter = logging.Formatter(form)
logHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)

# create logger
log = logging.getLogger('MyLogger')
logHandler.configureHeaderWriter('test-header', log)
log.addHandler(logHandler)
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Answer (score 2):

The solutions above cover the majority of use cases, but if you want to still respect the behavior of the `FileHandler.delay` attribute, I think the simplest solution is to override the `_open()` method:

```
class MyTimedRotatingFileHandler(TimedRotatingFileHandler):
    def __init__(self, filename, when='h', interval=1, backupCount=0, encoding=None, delay=False, utc=False, atTime=None, header=''):
        self.header = header
        super().__init__(filename, when, interval, backupCount, encoding, delay, utc, atTime)
    def _open(self):
        stream = super()._open()
        if self.header and stream.tell() == 0:
            stream.write(self.header + self.terminator)
            stream.flush()
        return stream
```

This way you could avoid ending up with "empty" log files containing only the header, and you don't have to worry about passing specific loggers to the handler.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a header in the first log file too, I propose an slightly modified alternative to your solution. Namely, an extra call to the piece of code that writes the header right after it is defined, and the interversion of some lines in the logger setup (see comments in the code):

```
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

class MyTimedRotatingFileHandler(TimedRotatingFileHandler):
    def __init__(self, logfile, when, interval):
        super(MyTimedRotatingFileHandler, self).__init__(logfile, when, interval)
        self._header = ""
        self._log = None

    def write_header(self):
        if self._log is not None and self._header != '': 
            self._log.info(self._header)

    def doRollover(self):
        super(MyTimedRotatingFileHandler, self).doRollover()
        self.write_header()

    def configureHeaderWriter(self, header, log):
        self._header = header
        self._log = log
        self.write_header()     # WRITE HEADER TO FIRST FILE

# create time-rotating log handler
logHandler = MyTimedRotatingFileHandler(logfile, when='midnight')
form = '%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s'
logFormatter = logging.Formatter(form)
logHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)

# create logger
log = logging.getLogger('MyLogger')

# CONFIGURE LOG LEVEL AND ATTACH HANDLER TO LOGGER **BEFORE** SETTING THE HEADER
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
log.addHandler(logHandler)  

logHandler.configureHeaderWriter('test-header', log)
```