# Uploading a csv type data using python request.put without reading from a saved csv file?

Tags: python, python-requests

i have an api end point where i am uploading data to using python. end point accepts

```
putHeaders = {
    'Authorization': user,

    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream' }
```

My current code  is doing this

.Save a dictionary as csv file

.Encode csv to utf8

```
dataFile = open(fileData['name'], 'r').read()).encode('utf-8')
```

.Upload file to api end point

```
fileUpload = requests.put(url,
                          headers=putHeaders,
                          data=(dataFile))
```

What i am trying to acheive is

loading the data without saving

so far i tried

converting my dictionary to bytes using

data = json.dumps(payload).encode('utf-8')

and loading to api end point . This works but the output in api end point is not correct.

[image]

Question

Does anyone know how to upload csv type data without actually saving the file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: use `io.StringIO()` as your file-like object when your writing your dict to csv. Then call `get_value()` and pass that as your data param to `requests.put()`.

See this question for more details: [How do I write data into CSV format as string (not file)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157314/how-do-i-write-data-into-csv-format-as-string-not-file).

Old answer:

If your dict is this:

```py
my_dict = {'col1': 1, 'col2': 2}
```

then you could convert it to a csv format like so:

```py
csv_data = ','.join(list(my_dict.keys()))
csv_data += ','.join(list(my_dict.values()))
csv_data = csv_data.encode('utf8')
```

And then do your `requests.put()` call with `data=csv_data`.

Comment: thanks Just a quick question . if i have multiple dic elements i put your code in for loop ?

Comment: I modified my answer. Turns out there's a much better way to do this I didn't think of.

Comment: @kkoc3 If this answered your question, feel free to upvote/mark mine as the accepted answer. Let me know if you have any more questions about this.

Answer (score 1):

#### Updated answer

I hadn't realized your input was a dictionary, you had mentioned the dictionary was being saved as a file. I assumed the dictionary lookup in your code was referencing a file. More work needs to be done if you want to go from a dict to a CSV file-like object.

Based on the I/O from your question, it appears that your input dictionary has this structure:

`file_data = {"name": {"Col1": 1, "Col2": 2}}`

Given that, I'd suggest trying the following using [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and [io](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html):

```py
import csv
import io

import requests

session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update(
    {"Authorization": user, "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"}
)

file_data = {"name": {"Col1": 1, "Col2": 2}}

with io.StringIO() as f:
    name = file_data["name"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=name)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows([name])  # `data` is dict but DictWriter expects list of dicts

    response = session.put(url, data=f)
```

You may want to test using the correct MIME type passed in the request header. While the endpoint may not care, it's best practice to use the correct type for the data. CSV should be `text/csv`. Python also provides a [MIME types module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/mimetypes.html):

```py
>>> import mimetypes
>>> 
>>> mimetypes.types_map[".csv"]
'text/csv'
```

---

#### Original answer

Just open the file in bytes mode and rather than worrying about encoding or reading into memory.

Additionally, use a context manager to handle the file rather than assigning to a variable, and pass your header to a `Session` object so you don't have to repeatedly pass header data in your request calls.

Documentation on the PUT method:

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.put

> data – (optional) Dictionary, list of tuples, bytes, **or file-like object** to send in the body of the Request.

```py
import requests

session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update(
    {"Authorization": user, "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"}
)

with open(file_data["name"], "rb") as f:
    response = session.put(url, data=f)
```

*Note:* I modified your code to more closely follow python style guides.

Comment: Hi Sorry this might be a stupid question but please bear with me as i am new to programming in general . when you say open the file in bytes mode what does that mean ? i dont want to save file i want data from my dic straight to request.post . So my data is in dic memory and from that dic momery location it goes to api as csv . i hope it makes sense

Comment: My bad, I assumed you were referencing a file in your dictionary lookup. Take a look at the updated answer.