# parsing csv string in python

Tags: python, string, csv, parsing

let's say I have a string like this

```
ab, "cd
ef", gh, "ijk, lm"
```

*and this*

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
```

and I want to parse them with python csv module. how can i do it? Second one is assumed it's two lines but first one is not.

I thought they'll needed to be loaded into `csv.reader()` so first thought I'll need to divide them by a comma so used `.split(',')` but it would have a problem on the second string, as it'll ignore the newline and I also thought of `.splitline()` but in this case it'll mess up the first string..

been trying to solve this for a whole day and i'm out of ideas... any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are having is that you have a space after the `,` so your actual delimiter is `', '` in the first example.

Luckily, you are not the first with this issue. Use [csv.skipinitialspace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.skipinitialspace) set to `True` to solve.

Given:

```
$ cat file1.csv
ab, "cd
ef", gh, "ijk, lm"
```

And:

```
$ cat file2.csv
a,b,c
d,e,f
```

You can do:

```
with open('file1.csv', 'r') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f, quotechar='"',skipinitialspace=True):
        print(f"len: {len(row)}, row: {row}")
```

Prints:

```
len: 4, row: ['ab', 'cd\nef', 'gh', 'ijk, lm']
```

And the same dialect works for the second example that has a true `,` delimiter without the trailing space:

```
with open('file2.csv', 'r') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f, quotechar='"',skipinitialspace=True):
        print(f"len: {len(row)}, row: {row}")
```

Prints:

```
len: 3, row: ['a', 'b', 'c']
len: 3, row: ['d', 'e', 'f']
```

Comment: thank you, this helped. However... what if the input was a raw string instead of the csv file itself?

Comment: You can use [io](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) or [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-StringIO) (depending on your Python version) to allow the csv library to treat a string as a file.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9157370/298607) is Tim Pietzcker's excellent example of using these libraries with the csv module.