# How to write the csv content to a variable in Python?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am trying to put a list of dictionaries in a csv format using the package csv. I am able to convert the list of dictionary in a csv file but I need the content to be written in a variable. Here is the code :

```
keys = dict_all_data[0].keys()
with open('all_data.csv', 'w')  as output_file:
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys, extrasaction='ignore')
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerows(dict_all_data)
```

In pandas, there is a simple way to put the csv content in a variable by not precising the name of the csv to write.

```
result = df_result.to_csv(index=False)
```

Is there a way to do this similarly with the package csv, please ?

Best regards.

Comment: What do you want your end variable to look like ?

Comment: `ifile = with open(...`:  SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Sorry, I removed the variable ifile.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write data into CSV format as string (not file)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157314/how-do-i-write-data-into-csv-format-as-string-not-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the generated csv to sring buffer ([`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/io.html#io.StringIO)):

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

# where to save the csv (string buffer)
s = StringIO()

# some data:
dict_all_data = [{'column_1':1, 'column_2':2}, {'column_1':3, 'column_2':4}]

# save the csv to string buffer:
keys = dict_all_data[0].keys()
dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(s, keys, extrasaction='ignore')
dict_writer.writeheader()
dict_writer.writerows(dict_all_data)

# print content of the buffer:
s.seek(0)
print(s.read())
```

Prints:

```
column_1,column_2
1,2
3,4
```

Comment: I did not mention that I work using Python 2.7. I tried your code using io.BytesIO and it works, thank you.