# Python read CSV file issue when the delimiter symbol itself is in the item

Tags: python, csv, delimiter

I'm trying to read a txt file (comma delimiter) into a CSV using csv.reader(). But because my delimiter (,) is sometimes inside the object/item the whole 'row' of read items get's shifted.

Example:

input.txt:

```
Stevenson Corp, 123 Main St, 3 employees\n
Johnson Inc, 456 Main St, 5 employees\n
```

would result in CSV columnized as:

```
Stevenson Corp | 123 Main St | 3 employees
Jonson Inc | 456 Main St | 5 employees
```

However, the issue arises if I have my input.txt file has (,) inside the items being delimitered, example:

input_bad.txt:

```
Stevenson Corp, 123 Main St, 3 employees\n
Johnson, Inc, 456 Main St, 5 employees\n #notice the comma before Inc
```

would result in in an incorrect CSV columnized as:

```
Stevenson Corp | 123 Main St | 3 employees #3 columns 
Jonson | Inc | 456 Main St | 5 employees #4 columns (issue)
```

I can't think of any solution to keep the Jonson, Inc together not split by the "," delimiter.

My code opens the txt file and csv as such:

```
inputfile = open(os.path.join(somelocation, somefile.txt), "r", encoding="utf-8", errors="replace")

csv_data = csv.reader(inputfile, delimiter = ",")
```

Please help.

Comment: You have an invalid CSV file. The string should have been enclosed in double quotes (`"`) if it contains the delimiter character. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475856/write-text-with-comma-into-a-cell-in-csv-file-using-python).

Comment: The whole purpose of a separator is that your csv is correctly formatted for it to be read. If it isn't then i'd suggest you do some pre-processing before reading it as a csv.

Answer (score 1):

Best approach would be to go back and change the delimiter in your file from `,` to something more sensible but if that's not an option so you can do something like this as a workaround:

```
import csv
with open(os.path.join(somelocation, somefile.txt), "r", encoding="utf-8", errors="replace") as inputfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(inputfile, delimiter='¬')
    for row in spamreader:
        new_row = row.rsplit(",", 2)
        print("|".join(new_row))
```

This uses a delimer not seen in your text so doesn't split any lines (so you could do the reading with `inputfile.readlines()` instead), then it uses `rsplit` to split on the two rightmost commas to create the columns

Comment: I do not have an option to change the delimiter. I'm presented with the file. And I'll try your solution.